# How can I restart the SSH daemon on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, services, sshd, upstart

When I type in `service sshd restart` I get a `sshd: unrecognized service` error.

I do have, in `/etc/ssh/` a file `sshd_config` that I use to set config. I can also putty into the Ubuntu box (it is remote).

When I type in `/etc/init.d/sshd restart` I get `No such file or directory`

Under `/usr/sbin/` there is an sshd file, but it is binary.

Is something wrong with my sshd? What do I do to fix this? To be clear, I want to be able to type `service sshd restart` (like all the online tutourials say) to be able to, well, restart my sshd. So that my port changes take effect.

Comment: post the output of `ls /etc/init.d | grep ssh`

Answer (score 172, accepted):

Ubuntu calls the service `ssh`, not `sshd`.

```
service ssh restart
```

The service is also controlled by upstart, and not sysvinit. So you'll find it at `/etc/init/ssh.conf` instead of `/etc/init.d/ssh`.

Comment: This answer no longer applies as of Ubuntu version 15.  The System 5 `rc` script notion is now _doubly_ out of date.  For updated answers, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/653865/ .

Comment: The first part of the answer still applies. Also note it should be `sudo service ssh restart`

Comment: 'sudo service ssh restart' works fine on ubuntu xenial.

Comment: works for ubuntu 1404

Comment: @JdeBP why did you link to an answer dealing with how to disable the autostart of SSHD, rather than dealing with how to restart SSHD?

Answer (score 3):

Most importantly you should have permissions to do so. Most of the problem like cannot start process or cannot find some file are due to permissions. Use `sudo` before any command.

Now for ssh you can simply do

```
sudo stop ssh
sudo start ssh
```

This leverages [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/)

Comment: this is really bad for remote servers, you can log yourself out with that first command and it's not automatically restarted.

Comment: @therealmarv reminds me of my first ip-tables remote configuration.  "iptables -A INPUT -j DROP"  ... then spending a while starting at a disconnected terminal wondering what happened.

Comment: I think it can be done in one command: `sudo restart ssh`. `service ssh restart` does not work in my Ubuntu 14.04.