# How to change the SSH Port for ubuntu 1404?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, port

similar question (CentOS 6.4): 
[Changing SSH Default Port 22 to 444](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/506656/changing-ssh-default-port-22-to-444)

similar question (restart the ssh daemon on ubuntu1404):[How can I restart the SSH daemon on Ubuntu?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127886/how-can-i-restart-the-ssh-daemon-on-ubuntu)

Comment: If I can not ask question about ubuntu1404, please tell me where i should ask in the stackexchange.com .

Comment: welcome to U&L, general question (such as this one) about ubuntu are fine here, very detailed question (location of depot for instance) can go to AskUbuntu site. however provided solution will work on any unix that support ssh, so it is fine here.

Comment: @Archemar sorry ,but AskUbuntu do not accept ubuntu1404 right now. I have tried. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1184330/how-to-enable-ssh-root-access-with-password-on-ubuntu-14-04/1184331#1184331

Comment: Well, sorry to hear it. As I said, your answer will work on many unix+ssh configuration, if not all.

Answer (score 1):

Warning: Make sure the new SSH port does not conflict with any known or blocked ports.

To Change the SSH Port for Your Linux Server

Connect to your server via SSH.

Switch to the root user.

Run the following command:

```
vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Locate the following line:

```
# Port 22
```

Remove # and change 22 to your desired port number.

Restart the sshd service by running the following command:

```
service ssh restart
```

reference (change to work on ubuntu 1404): 
https://hk.godaddy.com/en/help/changing-the-ssh-port-for-your-linux-server-7306